# Does the heartbleed bug necessitate new SSH private keys?

Tags: ssh, openssl, heartbleed-bug

This [guy says](https://twitter.com/dpkendal/status/453649454805942273):

> Debunking some Heartbleed FUD: You *don’t* need new SSH private keys. This affects the SSL *protocol* only.

My question is: **Does the heartbleed bug necessitate new SSH private keys?** (Or is this merely FUD?) [For systems that had the buggy version of the openssl library]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know you don't need to regenerate new key pairs (would be sensible anyway though). Heartbleed was a bug in the Heartbeat extension of OpenSSL for the keep-alive of a SSL/TLS connection.

Please see this article too: http://www.ssh.com/blog/12-ssh-communications-security-comments-on-heartbleed-vulnerability

Comment: Sure - just to clarify - isn't there a risk they've copied your keys out of memory?

Comment: @hawkeye, I can't answer that precisely. If they were in memory at the time of the attack (leak), then there is always a probability. I'd suggest you to regenerate the pairs anyway to have maximum security. edit: It's a good habit to regenerate keys after any exploit, such as this, has been discovered so late (2 years, sigh).